# Finding the tangent line through the origin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Find the tangent line to:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$$ that passes through the origin $(0, 0)$.

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}$$

The line will be tangent at $(a, b)$ so then:

$$f'(a) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a-1}}$$

Which is the slope.

$$y - \sqrt{a-1} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a-1}}(x - a)$$

Through $(0, 0)$

$$\sqrt{a-1} = \frac{-a}{2\sqrt{a-1}}$$

$$a-1 = -\frac{a}{2}$$

Am I heading the RIGHT direction? I dont need an answer, just advice.

Answer (score 1):

Except for a negative sign, you are fine.

A negative sign is omitted when substituting (x,y) with (0,0)

The rest is correct.

Comment: isnt point slope form: 

$$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$$?

Comment: It is correct however fix the next equation to:
$$-\sqrt{a-1} = \frac{-a}{2\sqrt{a-1}}$$